# Toggle Button Comes in to Focus Only after Clicking the List Item in the ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem, togglebutton

I have a Listview With two Textviews and toggle Button and i have ontoggleChangeListener for the Toggle Button. but if i click on the toggle button without clicking the list item it is not coming in to focus (that is listener is not Called ) but comes in to focus after clicking a listitem in the Listview

MY CODE SNIPPET :

```
alarmList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, final int pos,
            long arg3) {

        System.out.println("Item On click is Called");

        toggle = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.tg);
        toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out
                        .println("On click of the Toggle Button is called !!");
                if (toggle.isChecked()) {
                    System.out.println("Checked");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not Checked ");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

MY LISVIEW XML CODE :

```
    android:id="@+id/alarmlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#fff"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
```

MY TOGGLE BUTTON XML CODE :

```
    android:id="@+id/tg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="ToggleButton"
```

Answer (score 0):

To called the toggle button listener you need to remove toggle button code from onItemClick listener and put it outside the listener.

Answer (score 0):

> but if i click on the toggle button without clicking the list item it is not coming in to focus (that is listener is not Called ) but comes in to focus after clicking a listitem in the Listview

This is because the code inside your `onItemClick()` method is not run until it is clicked at least once.

You need to create a custom adapter and define the ToggleButton's behavior in the `getView()` method to have your button function in the manner you expect.

---

Something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.tg);
        toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out
                        .println("On click of the Toggle Button is called !!");
                if (toggle.isChecked()) {
                    System.out.println("Checked");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not Checked ");
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

(...But this particular example is not the most efficient method, please watch Android's Romain Guy [discuss creating fast adapters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA) for a wealth of information I cannot cram into the answer here.)